# Putting an event handler in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to figure out something and having issues with it. I have some icons data that I am receiving from an array inside an array and I want to put an event handler on only one of the icons. For example, let's say put an event handler on thumbs up icon to hide a paragraph (something like that).

I have made a codepen for demonstration: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNxdER

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-data-table
        v-model="selected"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        item-key="name"
      >
        <template v-slot:items="props">
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
          <td><v-icon v-for="icon in props.item.icons">{{icon}}</v-icon></td>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
        { text: 'Icons', value: 'icon'}
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          iron: '1%',
          icons: [
            'search',
            'dashboard',
            'timeline',
            'thumb_up'
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          iron: '1%',
          icons: [
            'search',
            'dashboard',
            'timeline',
            'thumb_up'
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          iron: '7%',
          icons: [
            'search',
            'dashboard',
            'timeline',
            'thumb_up'
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          iron: '8%',
          icons: [
            'search',
            'dashboard',
            'timeline',
            'thumb_up'
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this using `v-on`:

```html
<v-icon v-for="icon in props.item.icons" v-on="getIconHandlers(icon)">{{icon}}</v-icon>
```

with:

```js
getIconHandlers (icon) {
  if (icon === 'thumb_up') {
    return {click: this.thumbUpClickHandler}
  }
      
  return null
}
```

You will, of course, also have to define the function `thumbUpClickHandler`. More likely you'll want to pass some context for the current row to the click handler, which can be achieved by passing that extra information to `getIconHandlers` and capturing it in the closure of the listener:

```js
getIconHandlers (icon, otherStuff /* <- pass whatever you need */) {
  if (icon === 'thumb_up') {
    return {
      click: () => {
        this.thumbUpClickHandler(otherStuff)
      }
    }
  }
      
  return null
}
```

It is possible to do all of this inline in the template instead but I think it's easier to understand pulling it out to a separate method.

This is taking advantage of the object syntax supported by `v-on`, very similar to `v-bind`. It's documented at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on. The properties of that object are registered as listeners using the property keys as the event names and the property values as the corresponding listener functions. For the other icons I just return `null` though you could also return an empty object.

Vuetify will show a different mouse cursor for icons that have `click` listeners and doing it this way will only change the cursor for the `thumb_up` icon, which I assume is the intent here.

**Update:**

As only one event is required it is also possible to do this using the square bracket expression syntax for `v-on`/`@`. e.g.

```
@[getEventName(icon)]="onThumbIconClick"
```

Here `getEventName` would be a method such as:

```js
getEventName (icon) {
  return icon === 'thumb_up' ? 'click' : null
}
```

There's special handling inside `v-on` that ensures no listener is registered when the expression evaluates to `null`.

Personally I prefer the object syntax I described previously but for the sake of completeness I thought it worth a mention.

Answer (score 2):

After v-for attach a click event which will call a method, which you pass the item to.

`<v-icon v-for="icon in props.item.icons" @click="iconAction(item, icon)">{{icon}}</v-icon>`

In your method, you then can do something on the item based upon which item was clicked.

```
methods: {
  iconAction (item, icon){
    if (icon === 'thumbs_up') {
      // do somthing for thumbs_up
    } else if (icon === 'dashboard') {
      // do somthing for dashboard
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: short and sweet . Thank you